# removing the last comma and print the list inside square bracket

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term

nterms = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to generate? "))

# first two terms
n1, n2 = 1, 1
count = 0

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms == 0:
   print(f'The first 0 Fibonacci numbers are [].')
elif nterms == 1:
    print(f'The first 1 Fibonacci numbers are [1].')
elif nterms == 2:
    print(f'The first 2 Fibonacci numbers are [1, 1].')
# if there is only one term, return n1

# generate fibonacci sequence
else:
   print(f"The first {nterms} Fibonacci numbers are ", end = '')
   while count < nterms:
       print(*n1, sep=', ')
       nth = n1 + n2
       # update values
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
```

input: `10`

expected output: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]`

my output: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55,`

Answer (score 1):

You could just store your result in `list` and print it on the end. With such approach your program could be simplified!

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term

nterms = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to generate? "))

# first two terms
numbers = [1,1]
count = 2

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <=2:
   print(f'The first {nterms} Fibonacci numbers are {numbers[:nterms]}.')
# generate fibonacci sequence
else:
   while count < nterms:
       nth = n1 + n2
       # update values
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
       numbers.append(nth)
   print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using the `*` operator wrong. It looks like you are a beginner, so I suggest not using it until much later (if you're up for it, you can do some reading on it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-star-or-asterisk-operator/)).

To fix your solution nicely and easily, all you need to do is put the values into a list and print the list because this is the default format for printing a list. Like this:

```
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term

nterms = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to generate? "))

# first two terms
n1, n2 = 1, 1
count = 0

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms == 0:
   print(f'The first 0 Fibonacci numbers are [].')
elif nterms == 1:
    print(f'The first 1 Fibonacci numbers are [1].')
elif nterms == 2:
    print(f'The first 2 Fibonacci numbers are [1, 1].')
# if there is only one term, return n1

# generate fibonacci sequence
else:
   print(f"The first {nterms} Fibonacci numbers are ", end = '')
   nums = []
   while count < nterms:
       nums.append(n1)
       nth = n1 + n2
       # update values
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
   print(nums)
```

Also, if you'd like, you can also simply your program to this:

```
nterms = int(input("How many Fibonacci numbers would you like to generate? "))

n1 = 1
n2 = 1

nums = []
for count in range(nterms):
    nums.append(n1)
    nth = n1 + n2

    n1 = n2
    n2 = nth
print(f"The first {nterms} Fibonacci numbers are {nums}")
```